# How would I use an API key to locate the JSON of a website

Tags: api

I'm trying to find some JSON documentation for FortniteTracker.com's API, and I've already got my API Key for the website. How would I use the API Key in a URL to find the JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including the API Key in the headers of your request.

You should really look at the documentation though, I'm sure they have some examples on how to do it.

EDIT:

```
let apiKey = "YOUR API KEY GOES HERE"

const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const url = "https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/powerrankings/pc/NAE/Ninja"

fetch(proxyurl + url, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "TRN-Api-Key": apiKey,
  }
}).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

This code works in my browser. You needed to add your API key as a header.

Comment: 'https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/{platform}/{epic-nickname}'

Comment: That's all they gave me to work with. I know I need to use the API Key but I don't know how

Comment: Awesome. Thank you

Comment: Okay my message could not convey how grateful I am. I've been working at this for nearly four hours and I couldn't find the info I needed, and you just saved me damn near another 5 hours. Thank you so much

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :D